# Tell return type of function to use typeof value from parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, parameters, zod

Is there a way to infer the type of a property passed through a function without passing it through as a generic at the callee?

```
interface Externals<T> {
  validator: (schema: T) => void;
}

export async function createAction(schemaValue: z.AnyZodObject): Promise<(externals: Externals<SchemaType>) => Promise<void>> {
  type SchemaType = z.infer<typeof schemaValue>;
  return async (externals: Externals<SchemaType>): Promise<void> => {
    externals.validator(schemaValue);
  };
}
```

Then using the above method:

```
// whilst I'm using zod here, this could be any dynamic object
const schemaValue = z.object({
  translatedValue: z.string().or(z.number())
});
async function runAction(): Promise<void> {
  const action = await createAction(schemaValue);
  await action({
    async validator(schema) {
      // schema is of type SchemaType, but there's no intellisense as the
      // return type isn't correct on createAction
    }
  });
}
```

This doesn't work because the returnType of createAction is incorrect, I know i can change

```
export async function createAction<T>(schemaValue: z.AnyZodObject): Promise<(externals: Externals<T>) => Promise<void>> {
  return async (externals: Externals<T>): Promise<void> => {
    externals.validator(schemaValue as T);
  };
}
async function runAction(): Promise<void> {
  const action = await createAction<z.infer<typeof schemaValue>>(schemaValue);
  await action({
    async validator(schema) {
      // this works, schema is the correct type
    }
  });
}
```

The above works, but it's a very simple repesentation of what I'm achieving and there's a lot of "schemas" to pass through and highly dynamic, I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this without passing through z.infer as a generic type to the `createAction` method?

Comment: So this question depends on zod?  Maybe it should be tagged as such

Comment: Not necessarily, could be any dynamic object which is a schema, but I'll tag it either way

Comment: I think you can do this with `z.ZodType<T>` for a generic `T`. Never used it myself though, so the solution might need some more tweaking. Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WG43Mw

Comment: @Oblosys This works from the validator method, however internally the createAction doesn't know anything about the schema

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean with that, but there's also a confusion between schemas and values in the code, as you pass the schema `schemaValue` to `validator`, but with `createAction<z.infer<typeof schemaValue>>` and `as T` you assert the type to be the value type rather than the schema type.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `z.Schema<T>`.

When you use `schemaValue: z.AnyZodObject`, the generic is unknown since generics are only automatically inferred in parameters.

Full example:

```js
interface Externals<T> {
  validator: (schema: T) => void;
}
const schemaValue = z.object({
  translatedValue: z.string().or(z.number())
});
export async function createAction<T>(schemaValue: z.Schema<T>/*see here*/): Promise<(externals: Externals<T>) => Promise<void>> {
  return async (externals: Externals<T>): Promise<void> => {
    externals.validator(schemaValue as T);
  };
}
async function runAction(): Promise<void> {
  const action = await createAction(schemaValue); // see here
  await action({
    async validator(schema) {
      // this works, schema is the correct type
      // no infer
    }
  });
}
```